# How would I create a global Counter for AWS Lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

If I wanted to launch a lambda function every 2 minutes, that makes a call to an api with an index number. How would I store the index number for lambda to read upon initialisation and increment it by one every time the lambda function makes a successful api call?

I think that having a dynamo table just for a counter is overkill.

Comment: If you dont have concurrent Lambdas running: Just store a simple `.txt` file with the counter index number in S3?

Comment: @MaiKaY Yeah that could work. I was hoping for something along the lines of cloudwatch storing the variable. Something that would not really add to the lambda run time that much ideally.

Comment: You could also use AWS Step Functions. First State: wait for 2mins, Second State: call the API and execute the next Step Functions.

Comment: @MaiKaY I would leave the step function to run for 6 months or so, then re-invoke it with the previous counter?

Answer (score 7):

I would argue that using something else other than dynamoDB would be overkill.

DynamoDB is made for this exact purpose. And it is virtually free for your use case. And will only add around more or less 10ms to your run time. Very negligible compared to the cold starts your Lambda will be getting.

---

If you really want to trim both your DynamoDB cost and your Lambda runtime, you can cache the counter inside the Lambda container (outside your handler).

Assuming, there are no concurrent invocations (triggered via scheduled events only), I would do something like this for each invocation:

1. Check for cached counter value.
2. If `counter == 0`, read value from DynamoDB. If `counter > 0`, use that value.
3. Do whatever you want to do.
4. Increment counter in DynamoDB and the cached value.

Comment: Lambda function must be stateless. The cached counter isn't a safe option. Multiple instance of the function can be launched by lambda (even if you don't do concurrent call)

Comment: @Hugodby With that I may go with the DynamoDB option. It will only have one row, but if it's the most performant then meh

Comment: You can also use the update_item() DynamoDB API call from your Lambda function to update the counter in DynamoDB (rather than read it, increment it and write it back).

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out of the box, you could log messages to CloudWatch Logs. You could then create a metric filter to get an actual value.

You can even trigger CloudWatch events with this.

Answer (score 0):

Make your lambda handler callback/throw an error if the API call fail. Example for JS :

```
export.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  apiCall().then(resp => callback(null, resp).catch(err => callback(err));
}
```

Using CloudWatch you can get metrics about the lambda invocation and error. By using a math expression you can do invocation-error that will give you the number of successful call. You can define the period and the time frame.

[image: Lambda Counter]

If you need programmatic acces use the AWS CLI or AWS SDK.
[AWS CLI get-metric-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html)